# Argparse - How to Specify a Default Subcommand

Tags: python, argparse

I am using the argparse package of Python 2.7 to write some option-parsing logic for a command-line tool. The tool should accept one of the following arguments:

"ON": Turn a function on.
"OFF": Turn a function off.
[No arguments provided]: Echo the current state of the function.

Looking at the argparse documentation led me to believe that I wanted two--possibly three--subcommands to be defined, since these three states are mutually exclusive and represent different conceptual activities.  This is my current attempt at the code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser.set_defaults(func=print_state) # I think this line is wrong.

parser_on = subparsers.add_parser('ON')
parser_on.set_defaults(func=set_state, newstate='ON')

parser_off = subparsers.add_parser('OFF')
parser_off.set_defaults(func=set_state, newstate='OFF')

args = parser.parse_args()

if(args.func == set_state):
    set_state(args.newstate)
elif(args.func == print_state):
    print_state()
else:
    args.func() # Catchall in case I add more functions later
```

I was under the impression that if I provided 0 arguments, the main parser would set `func=print_state`, and if I provided 1 argument, the main parser would use the appropriate subcommand's defaults and call `func=set_state`.  Instead, I get the following error with 0 arguments:

```
usage: cvsSecure.py [-h] {ON,OFF} ...
cvsSecure.py: error: too few arguments
```

And if I provide "OFF" or "ON", `print_state` gets called instead of `set_state`.  If I comment out the `parser.set_defaults` line, `set_state` is called correctly.

I'm a journeyman-level programmer, but a rank beginner to Python. Any suggestions about how I can get this working?

**Edit**: Another reason I was looking at subcommands was a potential fourth function that I am considering for the future:

"FORCE txtval": Set the function's state to `txtval`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The defaults of the top-level parser override the defaults on the sub-parsers, so setting the default value of `func` on the sub-parsers is ignored, but the value of `newstate` from the sub-parser defaults is correct.

I don't think you want to use subcommands. Subcommands are used when the available options and positional arguments change depending on which subcommand is chosen. However, you have no other options or positional arguments.

The following code seems to do what you require:

```
import argparse

def print_state():
    print "Print state"

def set_state(s):
    print "Setting state to " + s

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('state', choices = ['ON', 'OFF'], nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.state is None:
    print_state()
elif args.state in ('ON', 'OFF'):
    set_state(args.state)
```

Note the optional parameters to `parser.add_argument`. The "choices" parameter specifies the allowable options, while setting "nargs" to "?" specifies that 1 argument should be consumed if available, otherwise none should be consumed.

**Edit:** If you want to add a FORCE command with an argument and have separate help text for the ON and OFF command then you do need to use subcommands. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying a default subcommand. However, you can work around the problem by checking for an empty argument list and supplying your own. Here's some sample code illustrating what I mean:

```
import argparse
import sys

def print_state(ignored):
    print "Print state"

def set_state(s):
    print "Setting state to " + s

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
on = subparsers.add_parser('ON', help = 'On help here.')
on.set_defaults(func = set_state, newstate = 'ON')
off = subparsers.add_parser('OFF', help = 'Off help here.')
off.set_defaults(func = set_state, newstate = 'OFF')
prt = subparsers.add_parser('PRINT')
prt.set_defaults(func = print_state, newstate = 'N/A')
force = subparsers.add_parser('FORCE' , help = 'Force help here.')
force.add_argument('newstate', choices = [ 'ON', 'OFF' ])
force.set_defaults(func = set_state)

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    args = parser.parse_args(['PRINT'])
else:
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

args.func(args.newstate)
```

Comment: A couple questions. 1) Will I be able to provide separate help text for 'ON' and 'OFF' in the usage statement? 2) I'm considering adding a fourth option, which takes an additional argument: "FORCE txtval". Is this doable in the current solution?

Comment: No the above solution does not allow separate help text for 'ON' and 'OFF' and a 'FORCE' command with an argument won't work with the above solution. I'll add another answer with a workaround in a moment.

Comment: Thanks, the if/else statement with `if (len(sys.argv) < 2):` did  the trick! However, it will ignore the rest of the arguments now. Let's say you wanto to run the script without command, resulting to 'PRINT'. But you want also provide the --newstate as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach.

First you probably already noticed that `newstate` is not some sub_value of the sub parser and needs to be addressed at the top level of `args` as `args.newstate`. That should explain that assigning a default to `newstate` twice will result in the first value being overwritten. Whether you call your programm with 'ON' or 'OFF' as a parameter, each time `set_state()` will be called with `OFF`. If you just want to be able to do `python cvsSecure ON` and
`python cvsSecure OFF` the following would work:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import argparse

def set_state(state):
    print("set_state", state)

def do_on(args):
    set_state('ON')

def do_off(args):
    set_state('OFF')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_on = subparsers.add_parser('ON')
parser_on.set_defaults(func=do_on)
parser_on.add_argument('--fast', action='store_true')
parser_off = subparsers.add_parser('OFF')
parser_off.set_defaults(func=do_off)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

The second problem is that `argparse` does handle subparsers as single value arguments, so you have to specify one before invoking `parser.parse_args()`. You can automate insertion of a lacking argument by adding a extra subparser 'PRINT' and automatically inserting
that using `set_default_subparser` added to `argparse.ArgumentParser()` (that code is part
of the package [ruamel.std.argparse](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/std.argparse)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import argparse

def set_default_subparser(self, name, args=None):
    """default subparser selection. Call after setup, just before parse_args()
    name: is the name of the subparser to call by default
    args: if set is the argument list handed to parse_args()

    , tested with 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4
    it works with 2.6 assuming argparse is installed
    """
    subparser_found = False
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg in ['-h', '--help']:  # global help if no subparser
            break
    else:
        for x in self._subparsers._actions:
            if not isinstance(x, argparse._SubParsersAction):
                continue
            for sp_name in x._name_parser_map.keys():
                if sp_name in sys.argv[1:]:
                    subparser_found = True
        if not subparser_found:
            # insert default in first position, this implies no
            # global options without a sub_parsers specified
            if args is None:
                sys.argv.insert(1, name)
            else:
                args.insert(0, name)

argparse.ArgumentParser.set_default_subparser = set_default_subparser


def print_state(args):
    print("print_state")

def set_state(state):
    print("set_state", state)

def do_on(args):
    set_state('ON')

def do_off(args):
    set_state('OFF')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_print = subparsers.add_parser('PRINT', help='default action')
parser_print.set_defaults(func=print_state)
parser_on = subparsers.add_parser('ON')
parser_on.set_defaults(func=do_on)
parser_on.add_argument('--fast', action='store_true')
parser_off = subparsers.add_parser('OFF')
parser_off.set_defaults(func=do_off)

parser.set_default_subparser('PRINT')

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

You don't need to handle in `args` to `do_on()`, etc., but it comes in handy if you start specifying options to the different subparsers.