# how to set argparse to exclude optional argument by values of positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

the arg include an action field and optional switches that modify the behavior of the actions.

the argparse code is like the below:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add-argument('action',metavar='action', choices=['analysis','report','update'],nargs='?', default='report')
parser.add-argument('-d',dest='delay',type=int, choices=range(1,10),default=1)
parser.add-argument('-v',dest='verbose',action='store-true',default=False)
parser.add-argument('-o',dest='offline',action='store-true',default=False)
parser.add-argument('-n',dest='names',required=False)
```

i want to make the switch option -o, -d, -v only available for action=report, while option -n only available for action=analysis.

i know there is a mutual group setting, but it is just set for the arguments not for the argument values!

btw, does argparse support combine options, like -vo...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Yes, combined options like -vo are supported

Now to the action switching:
Adding a SubParser to your ArgumentParser is exactely what you want to do.
See Section [15.4.5.1. Sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) in the Documentation of argparse, everything is explained to some detail and with example there

EDIT:
I know refer to your comment below this post:
If you do not provide a subcommand parameter in the program call, the parser normally gives you a kind advice how to use the program and then exits with a "too few arguments error"
I rewrote your code to show this

**test.py**

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

parser_analysis = subparsers.add_parser('analysis', help='analysis help text')
parser_analysis.add_argument('-n',dest='names',required=False)

parser_report = subparsers.add_parser('report', help='report help text')
parser_report.add_argument('-d',dest='delay',type=int, choices=range(1,10),default=1)
parser_report.add_argument('-v',dest='verbose',action='store_true',default=False)
parser_report.add_argument('-o',dest='offline',action='store_true',default=False)

parser_update = subparsers.add_parser('update', help='update help text')
parser.parse_args()
```

Now some calls of this `test.py` with different arguments:

```
$python test.py
usage: test.py [-h] {analysis,report,update} ...
test.py: error: too few arguments
$python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] {analysis,report,update} ...

positional arguments:
  {analysis,report,update}
                        sub-command help
    analysis            analysis help text
    report              report help text
    update              update help text

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
$python test.py report -h
usage: test.py report [-h] [-d {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}] [-v] [-o]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
  -v
  -o
```

So as I see it the only problem is that the program throws an error after calling `python test.py` without any subcommand. So I would do s.th. like this

```
try:
  args=parser.parse_args()
except:
  exit(0)
```

to avoid that the user sees that there was an unhandled error. You have then the same behaviour as i.e. the `svn` command.

If you want to handle this in the way that a default subcommand is executed, you whould have to do s.th. like mentioned in this post answer:

[Argparse - How to Specify a Default Subcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176691/argparse-how-to-specify-a-default-subcommand)

```
import sys
#...your parser definitions
if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    args = parser.parse_args(['update'])
else:
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This would parse a command `update` if the argument list in `sys.argv` is smaller than 2. Why 2? Because the first argument in the argument list is always the program which you called, i.e. `test.py`

The question is, do you really want this behaviour? Because there is no need for calling `test.py update` if i can always call `test.py`, so users will probably get lazy and never use `test.py update` command. Also if you later want a different default behaviour like `test.py` starting an interactive mode, users which are by then used to calling `test.py` for updating will get confused or their scripts which use your program get broken.

Comment: it works partially! looks like it treats the sub-commands as positional argument (usage & help), however, command-line without any sub-command would go passing the error check then break my app, it didn't trigger the usage msg when normal positional argument check failed, it also does not allow to set default value, like normal positional argument does. what i do now is to trap the sub-commands to handle if sub-command is None.... any better way to do it, like enforce sub-command, or set a default value to sub-command, tkyou!

Comment: Ok, I just expanded my answer to cover what I think your problem is.
Hope it helps

Comment: many tks for your answer... i bet you are running python2.x, mine is python3.3, running your test.py without argument will go pass argparse check (not showing the usage msg) but raise an error as in the code it made ref to arg.xxx but the argument is none. i searched elsewhere and found it is possible to make sub-command 'required', not as a parameter, but after the sub-parser call.. it looks like a bug for argparse in python3.x