# Specify default subcommand with positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176691/argparse-how-to-specify-a-default-subcommand) asked on SO, which doesn't address my own problem. For illustration purpose, say I have a Python program using `argpase` that provides two subcommands: `copy` and `resume`:

```
prog copy src dest  # src, dest positional, required
prog resume id      # id positional, required
```

However, the most natural way to invoke the "copy" command is **NOT** explicitly give the `copy` subcommand, that is, I was hoping for:

```
prog src dest
```

will do the default `copy` action, while still keep the benefits of have two subparsers, each handles a different set of arguments. Is it possible with `argparse` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally there isn't.  The subcommand argument is a required positional argument, where the 'choices' are the subparser names (and their aliases).

That's evident in the help message, were `{cmd1,cmd}` are shown as choices.

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] {cmd1,cmd2} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd1,cmd2}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

The latest Python has a 'bug' that actually lets it be optional.  In other words, it does not raise an error if you don't give any positionals.  It's a bug because it changes previous behavior, and most people what it to be required.  But even when it is optional, and `cmd1` defined as the default, it won't run the `cmd1` parser on the remaining arguments.  And any 'positional' argument will be treated as a wrong command string.

I think the best you can do is define one or more positionals.  One might have choices and default, and be optional (nargs='?').  The rest (or other) might has `nargs='+'`.  By playing around with those options you could approximate the desired behavior, but it won't make use of the subparsers mechanism.

---

Another way to think about the issue, is to consider an input like

```
prog one two
```

Should it interpret that as `prog src dest` or `prog cmd id`.  The only basis for saying it should be the former is the fact that `one` is not one of `copy` or `resume`.  But it isn't that smart when it comes to handling 'choices'.  It assigns a value based on position, and then tests whether it meets criteria like 'choices' or 'type' (ie. integer, float v string).

Comment: Though it is not exactly what I am hoping for, but I think it is as good as it gets. Thanks for taking the time to explain.